# How do I use a Maven 2 repository protected using SSL and a wildcard/self-signed certificate?

Tags: java, maven-2, ssl, keytool

I am trying to use a Maven 2 repository via SSL secured with a self-signed certificate. I followed the instructions at [HTTPS and Self-Signed Certificates in Java](http://cvs.peopleware.be/training/maven/maven2/selfSignedSslCertificates.html) but I doesn't to work.

I think its because the certificate is a wild-card certificate. So I wonder if I should be doing something different to import the wild-card certificate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was not the use of a wild-card certificate after all. I had to import the CA certificate I used to sign the server certificate into the **jssecacerts** keystore rather than **cacerts**:

```
keytool -keystore %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\jssecacerts -import -file cacert.pem
```

Comment: See http://www.sebsgarage.com/2012/09/adding-java-ssl-certificate-mac-osx/ for a simple way to generate the jssecacerts file, and follow-up discussion for OSX.

Comment: I had to use admin CMD, my path wasn't under `jre` (using Corretto) and it was `\security\cacerts` and not what OP has. This worked: `keytool -keystore "C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk17.0.6_10\lib\security\cacerts" -import -file "C:\mycacert.pem"`

Answer (score 2):

Rather the tampering with the certificates for all java applications, generate a separate certificate file that only maven uses, and then use MAVEN_OPTS to set the -D parameter.

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/private/${ACCOUNT}/java/keystore.pks 
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${PASSWORD}

See:
https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Maven+with+untrusted+SSL+Certificates

Answer (score 1):

- try using `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` as that page suggests and include the output
- validate your assumption that the problem is the wildcard - try it against a non-wildcard self-signed certification

Comment: I'm having similar problems with Maven and self-signed certs, and running Maven with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl seems to have no effect.